# How to read a text from a page using Helium?

Tags: java, testing, automation, helium

[image]

I want to read the text showing in the picture and want to print that text using Helium. I tried the following code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

//import com.heliumhq.selenium_wrappers.WebDriverWrapper;

import static com.heliumhq.API.*;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver ff = startFirefox("http://172.16.0.200:8001/");
        waitUntil(Text("Streams Tech, Inc.").exists);

        streamstech lg = new streamstech();
        lg.login(ff);
         if (getDriver().getValue().contains("You have not purchased any product yet. Please visit our product list to try out different products!"))
                System.out.println("You have not purchased any product yet. Please visit our product list to try out different products!");
            else
                System.out.println("Test failed :(");
        //String text = getValue("You have not purchased any product yet. Please visit our product list to try out different products!");
        killBrowser();
    }
}
```

But for getValue() I am getting an error "The method getValue() is undefined for the type WebDriver"
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried the following command 'String text = TextField($("//*[@id='ng-app']/div[2]/div[1]")).getValue();' but for this I am getting the following error 'The method TextField(SearchRegion...) in the type API is not applicable for the arguments (API.$)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem

```
Text("My desire text").getValue();
```

This command is reading the string